# Fancybox displays the first image twice

Tags: jquery, fancybox

it's about this page: http://axol.de/Axol/HTML/Projects.html

If you click on one of the Projects, you can see, that the first image is being displayed twice, and I can't figure out why. I'm using simplyscroll for the images sliding to the left and Fancybox for the galleries being displayed.

Anyone knows the solution? Could you somehow delete the first element of the fancybox array, so you simply delete the doubled element?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't from my side. What browser reproduces the issue? BTW, it would great if you add a [DOCTYPE](http://alistapart.com/article/doctype) to your page.

Comment: Damn. Now i uploaded the new page to the internet... I'm gonna reupload the version which doesn't work in a second! Can you tell me why it is important to add the doctype to your html document?

Comment: Why? Because it defines which version of (X)HTML your document is actually using, and this is a **critical** piece of information needed by some tools processing the document. http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Comment: But what if I'm not sure what I'm using? Becuase I learned html from different pages, etc. And I dont know if that's strict html or transitional html etc...?

Comment: If you want to play safe, then just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` (and forget about strict, transitional, loose, etc.) but don't let your document without `DOCTYPE`

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response! Right here: http://axol.de/HTML/Projects.html

Comment: It's seems like your scrolling script http://axol.de/js/jQuery.simplyscroll.js is cloning the images in the slideshow so this is why they appear twice. Not too much time to debug all third-party plugins :/

Comment: Hm... Can I somehow change the script? Or will I have to find another plugin?